# Javascript gradually change the saturation

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, addeventlistener

I have some code so that when the key c is pressed, the saturation will increase and when the key c is lifted, it will revert back to normal. I'm wondering how I can make it so that instead of instantly changing the saturation level, the saturation will gradually change throughout the course of half a second and when the key c is lifted, the saturation will gradually decrease throughout a  half second back to the normal saturation level. How can this be done?
Current code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.code === "KeyC") {
document.body.style.filter = "saturate(1.7)";

    
    
    
    }
}, false)

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.code === "KeyC") {
  document.body.style.filter = "";

  
  }
}, false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use use a CSS transition to get the gradual change.
Then instead of setting the saturate value with javascript you can just do `.classList.add('saturated')` and `.classList.remove('saturated')` on the element. I made an example with a div:

```
#myDiv{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  filter: saturate(1);
  transition: filter 1s ease;
}

#myDiv.saturated {
  filter: saturate(4);
}
```

here is a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martinnester/07fsL2ge/20/